# How do I manage app versions in all code instances?

Tags: version, versioning

I have a project in monorepo. It contains a whole bunch of files where the app version is mentioned:

```
./app/app.json <- expo.io
./app/package.json
./api/package.json
./cloud-functions/<15 cloud functions here>/package.json
etc...
```

I have various deployment scripts, each of them needs version number. Strictly speaking I have to update versions with each merge to the main `dev` branch in git.

Is there a common practice or something to manage version code in one place?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I use this, maybe someone will improve it?

```
#!/bin/bash

OLD_VERSION=`cat scripts/current-version-code`
echo $NEW_VERSION
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  read -p "Current version is $NEW_VERSION. What is new version? " NEW_VERSION
else
  NEW_VERSION=$1
fi

if [ -z "$NEW_VERSION" ]
  then
    echo "No version specified"
    exit 1
fi

sed -e "/\"version\":.*$/{s//\"version\": \"$NEW_VERSION\",/;:a" -e '$!N;$!ba' -e "}" -i '' 'api-server/package.json'
sed -e "/\"version\":.*$/{s//\"version\": \"$NEW_VERSION\",/;:a" -e '$!N;$!ba' -e "}" -i '' 'cloud-functions/deleteTransactions/package.json'
sed -e "/\"version\":.*$/{s//\"version\": \"$NEW_VERSION\",/;:a" -e '$!N;$!ba' -e "}" -i '' 'cloud-functions/emailSend/package.json'
sed -e "/\"version\":.*$/{s//\"version\": \"$NEW_VERSION\",/;:a" -e '$!N;$!ba' -e "}" -i '' 'cloud-functions/exportUsersBq/package.json'
sed -e "/\"version\":.*$/{s//\"version\": \"$NEW_VERSION\",/;:a" -e '$!N;$!ba' -e "}" -i '' 'cloud-functions/getWholesalers/package.json'
sed -e "/\"version\":.*$/{s//\"version\": \"$NEW_VERSION\",/;:a" -e '$!N;$!ba' -e "}" -i '' 'cloud-functions/mongoUpdateByWholesaler/package.json'
sed -e "/\"version\":.*$/{s//\"version\": \"$NEW_VERSION\",/;:a" -e '$!N;$!ba' -e "}" -i '' 'admin/package.json'
sed -e "/\"version\":.*$/{s//\"version\": \"$NEW_VERSION\",/;:a" -e '$!N;$!ba' -e "}" -i '' 'expo-app/package.json'
sed -i ''  "s|$OLD_VERSION|$NEW_VERSION|g" 'expo-app/app.json'
sed -i ''  "s|$OLD_VERSION|$NEW_VERSION|g" 'scripts/current-version-code'
```